# How to create custom column that calculates running MAX in Excel Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a power query that has a table like this:

| V | idx | mod |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| -10 | 4 | 0 |
| 12 | 5 | 1 |
| 0 | 6 | 2 |
| 9 | 7 | 3 |

Column "V" is my data, column "idx" is index column that I added and column "mod" is the modulo column that I added to be mod(idx,4). The "mod" column would eventually be used to filter rows, e.g. keeping only rows that have [mod] == 0.

I would like to add custom column "Vmax" that would calculate the running Max of V[i:i+3] where i is the starting row number. The resulting table should look like this:

| V | idx | mod | Vmax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| 10 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 12 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 12 |
| -10 | 4 | 0 | 12 |
| 12 | 5 | 1 | 12 |
| 0 | 6 | 2 | 9 |
| 9 | 7 | 3 | 9 |

I was able to accomplish this outside of the power query by implementing the "Vmax" column like this:

```
=MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1,3)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()+$G$1-1,1,3)))
```

where cell "G1" had a value of 4 that was used for modulo operation.

Is it possible to do the same within the Power Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add column, custom column, with

```
= List.Max(List.Range(#"PriorStepNameGoesHere"[V],[idx],4))
```

[image]

sample code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"V", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each List.Max(List.Range(Source[V],[idx],4)))
in  #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly well. Previous version used Source[V] which did not work. With #"PriorStep" it was good. Thanx.